# Rename python 3.7 executable without breaking stuff

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7

I have renamed `python.exe` to `python37.exe` to avoid conflict with other versions. It works for running python, but if I run `pip37.exe` (located in /Scripts) I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Python37-32\Scripts\pip37.exe"
```

Is there a way to keep `python.exe` renamed to `python37.exe`, but keep all python tools working?

Comment: Switch to linux, and it's trivial to fix ;). In python 3.7, pip is part of the standard library, so the recommended way to run pip is `python -m pip`. I recommend you do that instead of using `pip37.exe`. The `pip` / `pip37.exe` executable is pretty much just a wrapper around that command anyway.

Comment: You can use a symbolic link beside the executable (e.g. python37.exe -> python.exe) and run the specific version using the symlink. This will have no effect on fully-qualified paths in embedded scripts (e.g. embedded in pip37.exe). However, it still requires managing the order of installations in `PATH` to set which version runs via unqualified `python` in a command prompt. This is most easily addressed by activating a virtual environment, as created by Python 3's venv module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like A BAD IDEA.

There are tools designed to help you manage exactly this sort of thing. The best of which imho is `pyenv`: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

It's quite simple to install. It takes a bit of getting used to – wrapping your head around virtual environments – but it makes it all so much easier to work with ultimately.

E.g. On my system I have the following versions of python:

```
pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.10
* 3.5.6 (set by /Users/.pyenv/version)
  3.5.6/envs/core4
  3.6.4
  3.6.4/envs/core5
  core4
  core5
```

The one with the asterisk is currently the global version, which will be the one used from any default shell. I can change that using `pyenv global 3.6.4` for example. I can also create virtual environments. E.g. core4 and core5 are virtual environments I created for specific projects. Each of these will have their own different libraries installed by `pip install` and differing python versions. You can activate a virtualenv for a given shell session e.g. `pyenv activate core5`.

And if you're thinking "what on earth does this have to do with Windows", look here: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Windows+Subsystem+for+Linux&atb=v93-1__&ia=web and here: http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Python installs [PyLauncher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).  You don't need virtual environments or renaming tricks.  `py.exe` is in the standard Windows path, has command line switches to pick the Python version to use, and enables using "shebangs" to specify what version of Python to run for scripts:

```
py script.py          # Run the latest Python installed (or specified by PY_PYTHON environment variable).
py -2 script.py       # Run the latest Python 2 version installed.
py -3 script.py       # Run the latest Python 3 version installed.
py -2.7 script.py     # Run the specific Python version.
py -2.7-32 script.py  # Run the 32-bit specific Python version.
py -0                 # List Python versions installed.
```

Scripts can use shebangs similar to Linux:

```
#!python2
#!python3
#!python2.7
#!python2.7-32
```

To run pip with a specific version:

```
py -2.7 -m pip install ...
```

If you need still would like a virtual environment with a specific Python version, you can specify the version (e.g. `-3`) and use:

```
py -3 -m venv <my_env_name>     # to create an virtual environment
<my_env_name>/scripts/activate  # to activate that environment
```

Activation adds the virtual environment to the path, so `python` (not `py`) will run in that environment.  the `Scripts` directory in that environment will also be added to the path, so `pip` can be run directly as well to install packages in that environment.